# Adding swipe animations to mobile end of website

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, swipe, swipe-gesture

I have a website with an image gallery on a page. When an image is clicked, a modal pop-up window with backward and forward buttons overlays the screen, and it works just fine.

On mobile, however, I would like to have this modal window expand so that the image takes up 100% width of the screen. I'd like the arrows to disappear, and instead the user should be able to move left and right by swiping. Ideally, there would be a swiping animation.

How would you recommend implementing something like this? Are there any built-in CSS, jQuery, or Angular commands? I want to avoid adding whole libraries or plugins, but if there's something out there that works great, what is it?

Comment: is your app written in angular? cause this really isnt an angular question...

Comment: Yes, it uses Angular - I'm not too familiar with Angular, so if there was something within Angular that could help with this, I wouldn't know.

Comment: javascript/jquery would do this. since youre not familiar with angular you will probably need to learn how to wrap such components in angular but you might be lucky to find an angular package that can do it.

Comment: I saw this jQuery swipe Event https://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipe.asp , but I don't think it really provides a swipe animation. Or at least the example given doesn't.

Comment: You can hide the arrow buttons using css. And use ngTouch's swipe events like ng-swipe-left and ng-swipe-right for teh gestures. The swipe animation has to be done from your side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the question would be, how do you want your animation? Use the jquery swipe event (as well as swipeleft and swiperight) to add css to transform your elements of you want to include multiple things. There is also the jquery animate effect that you could bind to the swipe event.
If you want to keep it simple you could just stick to CSS (and risk breaking in older IE). Check out the reveal tab on this page in your mobile device: https://tympanus.net/Development/DragDropInteractions/reveal.html
Note: There's some amazing things you can do on this link using just pure CSS

Comment: Woah! Some nice things on that page. Thanks!